# How to handle errors from an API request with VueJS and Axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, swagger, vuejs3, openapi

I am working on a front-end project build with Vuejs and using Axios to interact with our API. The project is already build, and I must follow this way to build new components and modules. Creating a request to an example API outside this project and handling the errors is not a problem, the problem becomes when I have to do it the way the project is done, since I am finding difficult to follow the code. Up to this point, I can see the server response for the request through the "network" tab from the console, but I am not able to display it on the page.

Just as extra information (I am not sure if it is rellevant), the project is based in an authentication system, where the user needs a Bearer token which is generated for them during the registration, and this token gets updated every 15 minutes, so the application must refresh this authentication token. Also, through the API, the interfaces for the models of the instances are generated with Swagger and Openapi specification.

sign-in.ts:

```
private loginRequest(): void {
  const loginRequest: AuthApiLoginPostRequest = {
    body: {
      email: this.email,
      password: this.password,
    }
}

authApi.loginPost$(loginRequest).subscribe((response) => {
if (response) {
const res: LoginResponse = response.data;
updateToken(res.data?.access_token);
updateRefreshToken(res.data?.expires_in as number);
this.getUser(response.data.data?.access_token);
else {
>            //THIS ELSE IS TRIGGERED. THE SERVER RESPONSE SHOWS A 401 - UNAUTHORIZED. If I check the network for the "login" request, it shows an object with an errorCode and an errorMessage which I need to show to the user and I haven't been able to do it yet.
>         }
>     });
> }
```

sign-in.html

```
<visyon-card :hasImage="true" :hasSteps="false" v-on:keyup.enter="login()">
  <div class="signCognito__card u-p--xxxxl">
    <header class="u-mb-l u-align--left">
      <h3 class="signCognito__header">SIGN IN WITH COGNITO</h3>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="u-align--left">
        <visyon-text-input
          :errorMessage="emailErrorMessage"
          :hasError="emailError"
          :label="$t('SIGNIN_GLOBAL-EMAIL')"
          @update:modelValue="inputChange('email', $event )"
          v-model="email"
          inputMode="email"
          required
          name="email"
        ></visyon-text-input>
        <visyon-text-input
          :errorMessage="passwordErrorMessage"
          :hasError="passwordError"
          :label="$t('SIGNIN_GLOBAL-PASSWORD')"
          :passwordVisibility="true"
          @update:modelValue="inputChange('password', $event )"
          v-model="password"
          required
          type="password"
        ></visyon-text-input>
        <div class="signIn__forgot-password u-pb--xxxxl u-align--left">
          <router-link
            :to="{ path: '/forgot-password' }"
            class="signIn__forgotPassword--link"
            >{{$t('SIGNIN_GLOBAL-FORGOT_PASSWORD')}}</router-link
          >
        </div>
        <visyon-button
          :disabled="false"
          :text="$t('SIGNIN_GLOBAL-SIGNIN')"
          @on-click="login()"
          theme="-primary"
          :class="{'u-mb--l':accessError}"
        ></visyon-button>
        <p>Error:</p>
        <p v-if="showServerError">{{ showServerError }}</p>
        <visyon-inline-error v-if="accessError"
          >{{$t('SIGNIN_GLOBAL-ERR_VALID_EMAIL')}}</visyon-inline-error
        >
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</visyon-card>
```

auth-api.instance.ts:

export const authApi = new AuthApi(
{
basePath: axiosBaseUrl,
isJsonMime: () => false,
},
undefined,
axiosBackendClient
);

auth-api.ts (generated with openApi and Swagger)

```
`/* tslint:disable */
/* eslint-disable */
/**
 * Metaverse API
 * No description provided (generated by Openapi Generator https://github.com/openapitools/openapi-generator)
 *
 * The version of the OpenAPI document: 1.0.0
 *
 *
 * NOTE: This class is auto generated by OpenAPI Generator (https://openapi-generator.tech).
 * https://openapi-generator.tech
 * Do not edit the class manually.
 */

import { from } from 'rxjs';
import globalAxios, {
 AxiosPromise,
 AxiosInstance,
 AxiosRequestConfig,
} from 'axios';
import { Configuration } from '../configuration';
// Some imports not used depending on template conditions
// @ts-ignore
import {
 DUMMY_BASE_URL,
 assertParamExists,
 setApiKeyToObject,
 setBasicAuthToObject,
 setBearerAuthToObject,
 setOAuthToObject,
 setSearchParams,
 serializeDataIfNeeded,
 toPathString,
 createRequestFunction,
} from '../common';
// @ts-ignore
import {
 BASE_PATH,
 COLLECTION_FORMATS,
 RequestArgs,
 BaseAPI,
 RequiredError,
} from '../base';

import { ApiErrorResponse } from '../models/';
import { ApiLoginGuestRequest } from '../models/';
import { ApiLoginRequest } from '../models/';
import { LoginResponse } from '../models/';
import { LogoutSuccessResponse } from '../models/';
import { UserResource } from '../models/';
import { errorService } from '@/services/error.service';

/**
 * AuthApi - axios parameter creator
 * @export
 */
export const AuthApiAxiosParamCreator = function (
 configuration?: Configuration
) {
 return {
 /**
 *
 * @summary Login a Guest User
 * @param {ApiLoginGuestRequest} body Guest User to log in
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 */
 loginGuestPost: async (
 body: ApiLoginGuestRequest,
 options: AxiosRequestConfig = {}
 ): Promise<RequestArgs> => {
 // verify required parameter 'body' is not null or undefined
 assertParamExists('loginGuestPost', 'body', body);
 const localVarPath = `/login/guest`;
 // use dummy base URL string because the URL constructor only accepts absolute URLs.
 const localVarUrlObj = new URL(localVarPath, DUMMY_BASE_URL);
 let baseOptions;
 if (configuration) {
 baseOptions = configuration.baseOptions;
 }

 const localVarRequestOptions = {
 method: 'POST',
 ...baseOptions,
 ...options,
 };
 const localVarHeaderParameter = {} as any;
 const localVarQueryParameter = {} as any;

 localVarHeaderParameter['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

 setSearchParams(localVarUrlObj, localVarQueryParameter);
 let headersFromBaseOptions =
 baseOptions && baseOptions.headers ? baseOptions.headers : {};
 localVarRequestOptions.headers = {
 ...localVarHeaderParameter,
 ...headersFromBaseOptions,
 ...options.headers,
 };
 localVarRequestOptions.data = serializeDataIfNeeded(
 body,
 localVarRequestOptions,
 configuration
 );

 return {
 url: toPathString(localVarUrlObj),
 options: localVarRequestOptions,
 };
 },
 /**
 *
 * @summary Login a user
 * @param {ApiLoginRequest} body User to log in
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 */
 loginPost: async (
 body: ApiLoginRequest,
 options: AxiosRequestConfig = {}
 ): Promise<RequestArgs> => {
 // verify required parameter 'body' is not null or undefined
 assertParamExists('loginPost', 'body', body);
 console.log('required error');
 console.log(RequiredError);
 const localVarPath = `/login`;
 // use dummy base URL string because the URL constructor only accepts absolute URLs.
 const localVarUrlObj = new URL(localVarPath, DUMMY_BASE_URL);
 let baseOptions;
 if (configuration) {
 baseOptions = configuration.baseOptions;
 }

 const localVarRequestOptions = {
 method: 'POST',
 ...baseOptions,
 ...options,
 };
 const localVarHeaderParameter = {} as any;
 const localVarQueryParameter = {} as any;

 localVarHeaderParameter['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

 setSearchParams(localVarUrlObj, localVarQueryParameter);
 let headersFromBaseOptions =
 baseOptions && baseOptions.headers ? baseOptions.headers : {};
 localVarRequestOptions.headers = {
 ...localVarHeaderParameter,
 ...headersFromBaseOptions,
 ...options.headers,
 };
 localVarRequestOptions.data = serializeDataIfNeeded(
 body,
 localVarRequestOptions,
 configuration
 );

 return {
 url: toPathString(localVarUrlObj),
 options: localVarRequestOptions,
 };
 },
 /**
 *
 * @summary Logout a user
 * @param {string} authorization Bearer {access-token}
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 */
 logoutGet: async (
 authorization: string,
 options: AxiosRequestConfig = {}
 ): Promise<RequestArgs> => {
 // verify required parameter 'authorization' is not null or undefined
 assertParamExists('logoutGet', 'authorization', authorization);
 const localVarPath = `/logout`;
 // use dummy base URL string because the URL constructor only accepts absolute URLs.
 const localVarUrlObj = new URL(localVarPath, DUMMY_BASE_URL);
 let baseOptions;
 if (configuration) {
 baseOptions = configuration.baseOptions;
 }

 const localVarRequestOptions = {
 method: 'GET',
 ...baseOptions,
 ...options,
 };
 const localVarHeaderParameter = {} as any;
 const localVarQueryParameter = {} as any;

 if (authorization !== undefined && authorization !== null) {
 localVarHeaderParameter['Authorization'] = String(authorization);
 }

 setSearchParams(localVarUrlObj, localVarQueryParameter);
 let headersFromBaseOptions =
 baseOptions && baseOptions.headers ? baseOptions.headers : {};
 localVarRequestOptions.headers = {
 ...localVarHeaderParameter,
 ...headersFromBaseOptions,
 ...options.headers,
 };

 return {
 url: toPathString(localVarUrlObj),
 options: localVarRequestOptions,
 };
 },
 /**
 * Refresh auth token
 * @summary Refresh token
 * @param {string} token The refresh token
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 */
 refreshTokenTokenGet: async (
 token: string,
 options: AxiosRequestConfig = {}
 ): Promise<RequestArgs> => {
 // verify required parameter 'token' is not null or undefined
 assertParamExists('refreshTokenTokenGet', 'token', token);
 const localVarPath = `/refresh-token/{token}`.replace(
 `{${'token'}}`,
 encodeURIComponent(String(token))
 );
 // use dummy base URL string because the URL constructor only accepts absolute URLs.
 const localVarUrlObj = new URL(localVarPath, DUMMY_BASE_URL);
 let baseOptions;
 if (configuration) {
 baseOptions = configuration.baseOptions;
 }

 const localVarRequestOptions = {
 method: 'GET',
 ...baseOptions,
 ...options,
 };
 const localVarHeaderParameter = {} as any;
 const localVarQueryParameter = {} as any;

 setSearchParams(localVarUrlObj, localVarQueryParameter);
 let headersFromBaseOptions =
 baseOptions && baseOptions.headers ? baseOptions.headers : {};
 localVarRequestOptions.headers = {
 ...localVarHeaderParameter,
 ...headersFromBaseOptions,
 ...options.headers,
 };

 return {
 url: toPathString(localVarUrlObj),
 options: localVarRequestOptions,
 };
 },
 /**
 *
 * @summary Get auth user
 * @param {string} authorization Bearer {access-token}
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 */
 userGet: async (
 authorization: string,
 options: AxiosRequestConfig = {}
 ): Promise<RequestArgs> => {
 // verify required parameter 'authorization' is not null or undefined
 assertParamExists('userGet', 'authorization', authorization);
 const localVarPath = `/user`;
 // use dummy base URL string because the URL constructor only accepts absolute URLs.
 const localVarUrlObj = new URL(localVarPath, DUMMY_BASE_URL);
 let baseOptions;
 if (configuration) {
 baseOptions = configuration.baseOptions;
 }

 const localVarRequestOptions = {
 method: 'GET',
 ...baseOptions,
 ...options,
 };
 const localVarHeaderParameter = {} as any;
 const localVarQueryParameter = {} as any;

 if (authorization !== undefined && authorization !== null) {
 localVarHeaderParameter['Authorization'] = String(authorization);
 }

 setSearchParams(localVarUrlObj, localVarQueryParameter);
 let headersFromBaseOptions =
 baseOptions && baseOptions.headers ? baseOptions.headers : {};
 localVarRequestOptions.headers = {
 ...localVarHeaderParameter,
 ...headersFromBaseOptions,
 ...options.headers,
 };

 return {
 url: toPathString(localVarUrlObj),
 options: localVarRequestOptions,
 };
 },
 /**
 *
 * @summary Validate oauth token
 * @param {string} authorization Bearer {access-token}
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 */
 validateTokenGet: async (
 authorization: string,
 options: AxiosRequestConfig = {}
 ): Promise<RequestArgs> => {
 // verify required parameter 'authorization' is not null or undefined
 assertParamExists('validateTokenGet', 'authorization', authorization);
 const localVarPath = `/validate-token`;
 // use dummy base URL string because the URL constructor only accepts absolute URLs.
 const localVarUrlObj = new URL(localVarPath, DUMMY_BASE_URL);
 let baseOptions;
 if (configuration) {
 baseOptions = configuration.baseOptions;
 }

 const localVarRequestOptions = {
 method: 'GET',
 ...baseOptions,
 ...options,
 };
 const localVarHeaderParameter = {} as any;
 const localVarQueryParameter = {} as any;

 if (authorization !== undefined && authorization !== null) {
 localVarHeaderParameter['Authorization'] = String(authorization);
 }

 setSearchParams(localVarUrlObj, localVarQueryParameter);
 let headersFromBaseOptions =
 baseOptions && baseOptions.headers ? baseOptions.headers : {};
 localVarRequestOptions.headers = {
 ...localVarHeaderParameter,
 ...headersFromBaseOptions,
 ...options.headers,
 };

 return {
 url: toPathString(localVarUrlObj),
 options: localVarRequestOptions,
 };
 },
 };
};

/**
 * AuthApi - functional programming interface
 * @export
 */
export const AuthApiFp = function (configuration?: Configuration) {
 const localVarAxiosParamCreator = AuthApiAxiosParamCreator(configuration);
 return {
 /**
 *
 * @summary Login a Guest User
 * @param {ApiLoginGuestRequest} body Guest User to log in
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 */
 async loginGuestPost(
 body: ApiLoginGuestRequest,
 options?: AxiosRequestConfig
 ): Promise<
 (axios?: AxiosInstance, basePath?: string) => AxiosPromise<LoginResponse>
 > {
 const localVarAxiosArgs = await localVarAxiosParamCreator.loginGuestPost(
 body,
 options
 );
 return createRequestFunction(
 localVarAxiosArgs,
 globalAxios,
 BASE_PATH,
 configuration
 );
 },
 /**
 *
 * @summary Login a user
 * @param {ApiLoginRequest} body User to log in
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 */
 async loginPost(
 body: ApiLoginRequest,
 options?: AxiosRequestConfig
 ): Promise<
 (axios?: AxiosInstance, basePath?: string) => AxiosPromise<LoginResponse>
 > {
 const localVarAxiosArgs = await localVarAxiosParamCreator.loginPost(
 body,
 options
 );
 return createRequestFunction(
 localVarAxiosArgs,
 globalAxios,
 BASE_PATH,
 configuration
 );
 },
 /**
 *
 * @summary Logout a user
 * @param {string} authorization Bearer {access-token}
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 */
 async logoutGet(
 authorization: string,
 options?: AxiosRequestConfig
 ): Promise<
 (
 axios?: AxiosInstance,
 basePath?: string
 ) => AxiosPromise<LogoutSuccessResponse>
 > {
 const localVarAxiosArgs = await localVarAxiosParamCreator.logoutGet(
 authorization,
 options
 );
 return createRequestFunction(
 localVarAxiosArgs,
 globalAxios,
 BASE_PATH,
 configuration
 );
 },
 /**
 * Refresh auth token
 * @summary Refresh token
 * @param {string} token The refresh token
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 */
 async refreshTokenTokenGet(
 token: string,
 options?: AxiosRequestConfig
 ): Promise<
 (axios?: AxiosInstance, basePath?: string) => AxiosPromise<LoginResponse>
 > {
 const localVarAxiosArgs =
 await localVarAxiosParamCreator.refreshTokenTokenGet(token, options);
 return createRequestFunction(
 localVarAxiosArgs,
 globalAxios,
 BASE_PATH,
 configuration
 );
 },
 /**
 *
 * @summary Get auth user
 * @param {string} authorization Bearer {access-token}
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 */
 async userGet(
 authorization: string,
 options?: AxiosRequestConfig
 ): Promise<
 (axios?: AxiosInstance, basePath?: string) => AxiosPromise<UserResource>
 > {
 const localVarAxiosArgs = await localVarAxiosParamCreator.userGet(
 authorization,
 options
 );
 return createRequestFunction(
 localVarAxiosArgs,
 globalAxios,
 BASE_PATH,
 configuration
 );
 },
 /**
 *
 * @summary Validate oauth token
 * @param {string} authorization Bearer {access-token}
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 */
 async validateTokenGet(
 authorization: string,
 options?: AxiosRequestConfig
 ): Promise<
 (axios?: AxiosInstance, basePath?: string) => AxiosPromise<object>
 > {
 const localVarAxiosArgs =
 await localVarAxiosParamCreator.validateTokenGet(
 authorization,
 options
 );
 return createRequestFunction(
 localVarAxiosArgs,
 globalAxios,
 BASE_PATH,
 configuration
 );
 },
 };
};

/**
 * AuthApi - factory interface
 * @export
 */
export const AuthApiFactory = function (
 configuration?: Configuration,
 basePath?: string,
 axios?: AxiosInstance
) {
 const localVarFp = AuthApiFp(configuration);
 return {
 /**
 *
 * @summary Login a Guest User
 * @param {ApiLoginGuestRequest} body Guest User to log in
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 */
 loginGuestPost(
 body: ApiLoginGuestRequest,
 options?: any
 ): AxiosPromise<LoginResponse> {
 return localVarFp
 .loginGuestPost(body, options)
 .then((request) => request(axios, basePath));
 },
 /**
 *
 * @summary Login a user
 * @param {ApiLoginRequest} body User to log in
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 */
 loginPost(
 body: ApiLoginRequest,
 options?: any
 ): AxiosPromise<LoginResponse> {
 return localVarFp
 .loginPost(body, options)
 .then((request) => request(axios, basePath));
 },
 /**
 *
 * @summary Logout a user
 * @param {string} authorization Bearer {access-token}
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 */
 logoutGet(
 authorization: string,
 options?: any
 ): AxiosPromise<LogoutSuccessResponse> {
 return localVarFp
 .logoutGet(authorization, options)
 .then((request) => request(axios, basePath));
 },
 /**
 * Refresh auth token
 * @summary Refresh token
 * @param {string} token The refresh token
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 */
 refreshTokenTokenGet(
 token: string,
 options?: any
 ): AxiosPromise<LoginResponse> {
 return localVarFp
 .refreshTokenTokenGet(token, options)
 .then((request) => request(axios, basePath));
 },
 /**
 *
 * @summary Get auth user
 * @param {string} authorization Bearer {access-token}
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 */
 userGet(authorization: string, options?: any): AxiosPromise<UserResource> {
 return localVarFp
 .userGet(authorization, options)
 .then((request) => request(axios, basePath));
 },
 /**
 *
 * @summary Validate oauth token
 * @param {string} authorization Bearer {access-token}
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 */
 validateTokenGet(
 authorization: string,
 options?: any
 ): AxiosPromise<object> {
 return localVarFp
 .validateTokenGet(authorization, options)
 .then((request) => request(axios, basePath));
 },
 };
};

/**
 * Request parameters for loginGuestPost operation in AuthApi.
 * @export
 * @interface AuthApiLoginGuestPostRequest
 */
export class AuthApiLoginGuestPostRequest {
 /**
 * Guest User to log in
 * @type {ApiLoginGuestRequest}
 * @memberof AuthApiLoginGuestPost
 */
 public body!: ApiLoginGuestRequest;

 constructor(dataprovider?: AuthApiLoginGuestPostRequest) {
 if (dataprovider) {
 Object.keys(dataprovider).forEach((key) => {
 (this as any)[key] = (dataprovider as any)[key];
 });
 }
 }
}

/**
 * Request parameters for loginPost operation in AuthApi.
 * @export
 * @interface AuthApiLoginPostRequest
 */
export class AuthApiLoginPostRequest {
 /**
 * User to log in
 * @type {ApiLoginRequest}
 * @memberof AuthApiLoginPost
 */
 public body!: ApiLoginRequest;

 constructor(dataprovider?: AuthApiLoginPostRequest) {
 if (dataprovider) {
 Object.keys(dataprovider).forEach((key) => {
 (this as any)[key] = (dataprovider as any)[key];
 });
 }
 }
}

/**
 * Request parameters for logoutGet operation in AuthApi.
 * @export
 * @interface AuthApiLogoutGetRequest
 */
export class AuthApiLogoutGetRequest {
 /**
 * Bearer {access-token}
 * @type {string}
 * @memberof AuthApiLogoutGet
 */
 public authorization!: string;

 constructor(dataprovider?: AuthApiLogoutGetRequest) {
 if (dataprovider) {
 Object.keys(dataprovider).forEach((key) => {
 (this as any)[key] = (dataprovider as any)[key];
 });
 }
 }
}

/**
 * Request parameters for refreshTokenTokenGet operation in AuthApi.
 * @export
 * @interface AuthApiRefreshTokenTokenGetRequest
 */
export class AuthApiRefreshTokenTokenGetRequest {
 /**
 * The refresh token
 * @type {string}
 * @memberof AuthApiRefreshTokenTokenGet
 */
 public token!: string;

 constructor(dataprovider?: AuthApiRefreshTokenTokenGetRequest) {
 if (dataprovider) {
 Object.keys(dataprovider).forEach((key) => {
 (this as any)[key] = (dataprovider as any)[key];
 });
 }
 }
}

/**
 * Request parameters for userGet operation in AuthApi.
 * @export
 * @interface AuthApiUserGetRequest
 */
export class AuthApiUserGetRequest {
 /**
 * Bearer {access-token}
 * @type {string}
 * @memberof AuthApiUserGet
 */
 public authorization!: string;

 constructor(dataprovider?: AuthApiUserGetRequest) {
 if (dataprovider) {
 Object.keys(dataprovider).forEach((key) => {
 (this as any)[key] = (dataprovider as any)[key];
 });
 }
 }
}

/**
 * Request parameters for validateTokenGet operation in AuthApi.
 * @export
 * @interface AuthApiValidateTokenGetRequest
 */
export class AuthApiValidateTokenGetRequest {
 /**
 * Bearer {access-token}
 * @type {string}
 * @memberof AuthApiValidateTokenGet
 */
 public authorization!: string;

 constructor(dataprovider?: AuthApiValidateTokenGetRequest) {
 if (dataprovider) {
 Object.keys(dataprovider).forEach((key) => {
 (this as any)[key] = (dataprovider as any)[key];
 });
 }
 }
}

/**
 * AuthApi - object-oriented interface
 * @export
 * @class AuthApi
 * @extends {BaseAPI}
 */
export class AuthApi extends BaseAPI {
 /**
 *
 * @summary Login a Guest User
 * @param {AuthApiLoginGuestPostRequest} requestParameters Request parameters.
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 * @memberof AuthApi
 */
 public loginGuestPost(
 requestParameters: AuthApiLoginGuestPostRequest,
 options?: AxiosRequestConfig
 ) {
 return AuthApiFp(this.configuration)
 .loginGuestPost(requestParameters.body, options)
 .then((request) => request(this.axios, this.basePath));
 }

 /**
 *
 * @summary Login a user
 * @param {AuthApiLoginPostRequest} requestParameters Request parameters.
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 * @memberof AuthApi
 */
 public loginPost(
 requestParameters: AuthApiLoginPostRequest,
 options?: AxiosRequestConfig
 ) {
 return AuthApiFp(this.configuration)
 .loginPost(requestParameters.body, options)
 .then((request) => request(this.axios, this.basePath));
 }

 /**
 *
 * @summary Logout a user
 * @param {AuthApiLogoutGetRequest} requestParameters Request parameters.
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 * @memberof AuthApi
 */
 public logoutGet(
 requestParameters: AuthApiLogoutGetRequest,
 options?: AxiosRequestConfig
 ) {
 return AuthApiFp(this.configuration)
 .logoutGet(requestParameters.authorization, options)
 .then((request) => request(this.axios, this.basePath));
 }

 /**
 * Refresh auth token
 * @summary Refresh token
 * @param {AuthApiRefreshTokenTokenGetRequest} requestParameters Request parameters.
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 * @memberof AuthApi
 */
 public refreshTokenTokenGet(
 requestParameters: AuthApiRefreshTokenTokenGetRequest,
 options?: AxiosRequestConfig
 ) {
 return AuthApiFp(this.configuration)
 .refreshTokenTokenGet(requestParameters.token, options)
 .then((request) => request(this.axios, this.basePath));
 }

 /**
 *
 * @summary Get auth user
 * @param {AuthApiUserGetRequest} requestParameters Request parameters.
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 * @memberof AuthApi
 */
 public userGet(
 requestParameters: AuthApiUserGetRequest,
 options?: AxiosRequestConfig
 ) {
 return AuthApiFp(this.configuration)
 .userGet(requestParameters.authorization, options)
 .then((request) => request(this.axios, this.basePath));
 }

 /**
 *
 * @summary Validate oauth token
 * @param {AuthApiValidateTokenGetRequest} requestParameters Request parameters.
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 * @memberof AuthApi
 */
 public validateTokenGet(
 requestParameters: AuthApiValidateTokenGetRequest,
 options?: AxiosRequestConfig
 ) {
 return AuthApiFp(this.configuration)
 .validateTokenGet(requestParameters.authorization, options)
 .then((request) => request(this.axios, this.basePath));
 }

 /**
 *
 * @summary Login a Guest User as Observable
 * @param {AuthApiLoginGuestPostRequest} requestParameters Request parameters.
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 * @memberof AuthApi
 */
 public loginGuestPost$(
 requestParameters: AuthApiLoginGuestPostRequest,
 options?: AxiosRequestConfig
 ) {
 return from(this.loginGuestPost(requestParameters, options));
 }

 /**
 *
 * @summary Login a user as Observable
 * @param {AuthApiLoginPostRequest} requestParameters Request parameters.
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 * @memberof AuthApi
 */
 public loginPost$(
 requestParameters: AuthApiLoginPostRequest,
 options?: AxiosRequestConfig
 ) {
 return from(this.loginPost(requestParameters, options));
 }

 /**
 *
 * @summary Logout a user as Observable
 * @param {AuthApiLogoutGetRequest} requestParameters Request parameters.
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 * @memberof AuthApi
 */
 public logoutGet$(
 requestParameters: AuthApiLogoutGetRequest,
 options?: AxiosRequestConfig
 ) {
 return from(this.logoutGet(requestParameters, options));
 }

 /**
 * Refresh auth token
 * @summary Refresh token as Observable
 * @param {AuthApiRefreshTokenTokenGetRequest} requestParameters Request parameters.
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 * @memberof AuthApi
 */
 public refreshTokenTokenGet$(
 requestParameters: AuthApiRefreshTokenTokenGetRequest,
 options?: AxiosRequestConfig
 ) {
 return from(this.refreshTokenTokenGet(requestParameters, options));
 }

 /**
 *
 * @summary Get auth user as Observable
 * @param {AuthApiUserGetRequest} requestParameters Request parameters.
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 * @memberof AuthApi
 */
 public userGet$(
 requestParameters: AuthApiUserGetRequest,
 options?: AxiosRequestConfig
 ) {
 return from(this.userGet(requestParameters, options));
 }

 /**
 *
 * @summary Validate oauth token as Observable
 * @param {AuthApiValidateTokenGetRequest} requestParameters Request parameters.
 * @param {*} [options] Override http request option.
 * @throws {RequiredError}
 * @memberof AuthApi
 */
 public validateTokenGet$(
 requestParameters: AuthApiValidateTokenGetRequest,
 options?: AxiosRequestConfig
 ) {
 return from(this.validateTokenGet(requestParameters, options));
 }
}`
```

Anyone could give me a hand to understand how it works? Thank you

I am trying to get on console the value for the request response from the server. The user must be able to see the error code and the error message that the server is giving after the login() request.

I have tried to do so outside this project, just following tutorials about vueJS, but I am not able to see how to work with this requests, as I recently started with Vue, and the code from the tutorials or pieces of code that I found about Axios request has nothing to do with the code I am seeing here.

Comment: It's unclear what you ask about, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . "but I am not able to see how to work with this request" - this is irrelevant to Vue, this is common JS/TS knowledge. It looks like you're dealing with code that exceeds your current skillset, actually it's too complex. The whole "generated with openApi and Swagger" thing makes it unnecessarily complicated. It uses observables (rxjs) that aren't usual in Vue. It could possibly be written in simpler way without losing design and functionality.

Comment: If you're about to dig into the code without rewriting it from scratch and need something to start quickly, consider checking observables first and how they interact with promises ("from" thing), check https://www.learnrxjs.io/ and official rxjs docs. You'd get an error in 2nd subscribe callback like `.loginPost$(loginRequest).subscribe((response) => { ... }, (error) => { ... })`. As said, observables ($ methods) aren't really usable here, it would make sense to use promises directly, like `authApi.loginPost(loginRequest)`

Comment: I don't know if the swagger/openapi generation is unnecessarily complicated. I just know that without them, I can not get the files that I need to create the request. The project itself is overwhelming me.

I have tried to do a basic get and post request with vuejs and axios, and I haven't found problems with it. The problems become trying to do it the way is already done.
I will have a look to this observables, the interaction with Promises and observables, as I didn't even know that the $ methods are observables! 

Thank you for your tips @EstusFlask!

Comment: The `if(response)` branch in `authApi.loginPost$` subscriber fn is not closed. Is that a typo? Also, what do you see in network tab when making the requests? Do they return with the expected response or do they return any sort of error (e.g: `403`?)

Comment: @eve_mf Consider this middle/senior TS code, so if you're relatively new to the subject, you may need at least JS+TS crash course with some focus on rxjs to deal with it properly. $ is just a convention that allows to spot observables at first sight. Observables are much more popular in Angular than Vue for several reasons, possibly they were introduced by devs with that background

Answer (score 0):

Usually you use interceptors to handle 401 and 403 in vueJs applications. But it also depends highly on your auth flow that you use. If I can assume that you on the login page and just want to handle it there you can just expose the promise to the view and handle it in a separated script.
AxiosPromise is not the best way to implement a HTTPClient in my experience. I am used to the Angular/React/NextJs way and they work with observables. You can use AxiosObservable in order to do so. Working with observables instead of promises provide a more flexible way to handle and operate on your httpresponses.

Here are some useful links:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-observable

https://medium.com/@p.woltschkow/a-better-practice-to-implement-http-client-in-vue-with-rxjs-c59f93bfa439

https://auth0.com/blog/javascript-promises-vs-rxjs-observables/